# how to print only one key of a python dictionary per line

Tags: python, dictionary

so have this dict `avgTemp = {1945: 51.75, 1946: 52.95, 1947: 51.92, 1948: 51.61,....}`
where the key correspond to year and the value is the avg temperature. i use map to map out the value of the dict with:

```
FahrtoCelc = list(map(lambda x:((x - 32) * 5 / 9), avgTemp.values()))
```

then i want to print out this value correspond to the year in the dict using :

```
for i in range(len(avgTemp )):
print(avgTemp.keys(), " : ", FahrtoCelc[i])
```

but end up with an answer that is not as i wanted it, how do i print 'year : converted temp'

Comment: is there a way using map ?, i required to use map function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the items() method of your dictionary:

```
avgTemp = {1945: 51.75, 1946: 52.95, 1947: 51.92, 1948: 51.61}

print(*(f"{y} : {(t-32)*5/9:02.2f}°C" for y,t in avgTemp.items()),sep="\n")

1945 : 10.97°C
1946 : 11.64°C
1947 : 11.07°C
1948 : 10.89°C
```

If you want to play with map(), you can use it in place of the comprehension:

```
FtoC = lambda yt: f"{yt[0]} : {(yt[1]-32)*5/9:02.2f}°C"

print(*map(FtoC,avgTemp.items()),sep="\n")
```

without format strings:

```
FtoC = lambda yt: str(yt[0]) + " : " + str(round((yt[1]-32)*5/9,2)) + "°C"
```

Comment: for FtoC is there a version not using f-string formating but still round the temperature value?, my lecturer has not teach us f-string formating yet

Comment: You could use string conversions with str() and the round() function

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
avgTemp = {1945: 51.75, 1946: 52.95, 1947: 51.92, 1948: 51.61}

for year, temperature in avgTemp.items():
    print(f"{year} - {round((temperature - 32) * 5 / 9, 2)}C")
```

Output:

```
1945 - 10.97C
1946 - 11.64C
1947 - 11.07C
1948 - 10.89C
```

Comment: is there an answer using map function?

Comment: @AndreCitro yes this is straight-forward to convert to a mapping.

Comment: @AndreCitro why would you want to use a `map` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Use dict comprehension to save keys in `FahrtoCelc` variable:

```py
FahrtoCelc = {year: ((x - 32) * 5 / 9) for year, x in avgTemp.items()}

for year, temperature in FahrtoCelc:
    print(year, ":", temperature)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the join statement which gives this one-liner:

```
print('\n'.join('{} - {}'.format(*item) for item in avgTemp.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use `map` you have to apply it when creating the new dictionary.

```
avgTemp = {1945: 51.75, 1946: 52.95, 1947: 51.92, 1948: 51.61,}
celsius = dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1] - 32) * 5 / 9), avgTemp.items()))
```

Now you can loop over the celsius dictionary.

```
for key, value in celsius.items():
    print(f'{key}: {value}°C'
```